# How to avoid decimal truncation in javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe

In my code I have some exp operation with decimals
I did some tests for example this operation

```
let c = 1.02;
let y = 0.0416666666666664;
let j= Math.pow(c,y); -> 1.000825449967136
```

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7CGo.jpg)]

But if I do the same thing with the calculator, I get this result instead -> 1.0008254499671359597325523766889
How to make the result of my operation as precise as in the calculator?
I've seen a few other similar questions, some recommended using BigInt, but in my case I can't use external js (or I don't think I can use it in Adobe Pro related javascript)

Comment: That calculator is outputting 31 decimal places, but it's still an approximation. If all you just want the "precision", you can use `toFixed(..)` to make JS print out more decimal places (e.g. `j.toFixed(31) === 1.0008254499671358495049844350433`). If you _need_ accuracy of exponentiation results in the 15th decimal place (why??) then you will need to use an external library such as [bigdecimal.js](https://github.com/iriscouch/bigdecimal.js) or [Math.js](https://mathjs.org) or your own arithmetic code that duplicates their work.